# How to make percentage bar chart of topics from topic modeling?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have been racking my brain on this for a week.

I want to

1. run NMF topic modeling
2. Assign each document a topic by looking at the maximum of weights,
3. Graph this distribution as a % bar chart using matplot. (I.e: Topics on the X axis, and % documents that are that topic on the y axis. )

Here is some toy data and completing steps 1 and 2:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
import pandas as pd

# Get data
data = {
    "Documents": ["I am a document", 
                  "And me too", 
                  "The cat is big",
                  "The dog is big"
                  "My headphones are large", 
                  "My monitor has rabies", 
                  "My headphones are loud"
                  "The street is loud "]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Fit a TFIDF vectorizer 
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Documents'])

# Run NMF
nmf_model = NMF(n_components=4, random_state=1).fit(tfidf)

# Weights
W = nmf_model.transform(tfidf)

# Topics
H= nmf_model.components_
```

Now here is how I can assign a document to a topcic:

```
# Will return document topics as list like [1, 4, 1...] to 
# represent that the first document is topic 1, the second 4, and so on. 
topics = pd.DataFrame(W).idxmax(axis=1, skipna=True).tolist()
```

Alright now I should be able to get what I want with these two structures but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a use case for a Counter().
I'd write something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

mylist = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,1,1]
mycount = Counter(mylist)
for key,value in mycount.items():
    print(key,value)
```

This outputs your topics in the following structure:

```
1 9
2 3
3 2
```

One thing to note for Latent dirichlet / non negative matrix is that the entire point is a sentence is composed of multiple topics. Maxing the weight to assign each to a single topic may defeat the purpose. You also may want to consider how to deal with nonsense sentences, as your algorithm will auto assign them to a topic currently.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to draw a bar char, so do not change topics into list:

```
topics = pd.DataFrame(W).idxmax(axis=1, skipna=True)

plt.bar(x=topics.index, height=topics.mul(100)/topics.sum())
plt.show()
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: Yeah is there anyway to make that without it looking weird (i.e: extra xaticks)

Comment: Those extra `xticks` corresponds to those topics with zero counts. You can drop them by `tmp = topics[topics.ne(0)]` and replace all the `topics` inside `bar` with `tmp`.